# What are the finite subgroups of $K^*$ if $K\in \{\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C\}$?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

What are the **finite** subgroups of $K^*$ if $K\in \{\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C\}$?

Comment: What is $K^* {}{}{}{}$?

Comment: @copper.hat As far as I know it usually is $K\setminus \{0\}$ and we're considering the product.

Comment: @GitGud: Thanks! I think $K^\times$ is also used.

Comment: Hint: Consider an element of maximal order $m$ and look at the polynomial $x^m - 1$.

Comment: If $x \in K^*$, then $x^n \in K^*$, and since finite, that says something about $|x|$.

Comment: $A^*$ is commonly used to denote the set of units in a ring $A$, thus $K$ field implies $K^* = K\backslash \{0\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $G$ is a finite group of $K^*$, say $|G|=n$, then $x^n=1$ for all $x \in G$. Now think about the elements $x$ in  $\Bbb Q, \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ that satisfy equations like $x^n=1$.

Comment: can't see the difference between rationals and reals?

Comment: @HELP there's no difference, the real solutions to $x^n = 1$ are also rational.

Comment: still no idea what to do

Comment: @HELP You get better hints if you are more specific about what is giving you problems.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $K$ is a field, then every finite subgroup of $K^*$ is cyclic. If it is order $n$, then it is therefore generated by an element of order $n$. Such elements are also known as primitive $n$ths roots of unity. If there is a primitive $n$th root of unity, then also for all divisors of $n$.

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, it has a primitive $n$th root of unity for every $n$. So the question is only which of these are real or even rational. But they all have absolute value $1$, and $S^1 \cap \mathbb{R} = S^1 \cap \mathbb{Q} = \{\pm 1\}$.

Summary: For every $n \geq 1$ there is a unique finite subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$ of order $n$. For $\mathbb{R}^*$ and $\mathbb{Q}^*$ this is only the case for $n=1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think as @copper.hat suggested, you are looking for the torsion subgroups of these groups. $$t(\mathbb Q^*,\cdot)=t(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)=\{\pm1\}$$

Comment: There are infinite torsion subgroups of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @JSchlather: Yes I know that. In fact $t(\mathbb C^*,\cdot)=\{\exp(2ki\pi/n),~~n,k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: Helpful, again! +1

Answer (score 0):

Of course all other answers are right and complete but I just want to point out the following not so difficult point

> Let $G$ be an finitely generated abelian group. If for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is at most $n$ elements in $G$ satisfying \begin{equation}n\cdot g=0,\end{equation}then $G$ is cyclic.

$n\cdot g$ means you add $n$ copies of $g$. This is not difficult once one is willing to apply the structure theorem for finite generated abelian groups.

In articular any finite subgroup $K^*$ of the multiplicative group of a field must be abelian and since $x^n=1$ has at most $n$ solutions, the fact above says $K^*$ is cyclic. That is, finite subgroups of multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.

Applying this to $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ gives the desired answers.